# Joomla Insert and delete from SQL without refresh

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Could somebody help me..I try to post fomr without page refresh but form work correctly only when i try to inserto or delete . now together. This sample works but when i delete "//"
from php form does not insert or delete to sql. Could somebody help me ?

WORK ONLY WHEN I OFF "IF" FROM PHP LIKE

```
PHP
    function addToFav() {
     global $Itemid;
        $user =& JFactory::getUser();
        $db2 =& JFactory::getDBO();
        $mediaid = $_POST['addMediaId'];
        $delid = $_POST['delRow'];
```

from this place something goes wrong when i delete "//" from rows

```
//if(isset($_POST['submit2']) and $_POST['submit2'] == '1') {             
  $query = ' INSERT INTO `#__mediamall_favourite_media` (`id`, `userid`, `mediaid`) VALUES ("","'.$user->id.'","'.$mediaid.'")';

// }    
//elseif(isset($_POST['submit2']) and $_POST['submit2'] == '0') {     
//$query = ' DELETE FROM #__mediamall_favourite_media WHERE id = "'.$delid.'" '; 
//}  

if($query) {
   $db2->setQuery($query);
   $db2->query();
   mosRedirect('index.php?option=com_mediamall&task=viewdetails&id='.$mediaid.'&Itemid=' . $Itemid);
}

}
```

FORM

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" id="myForm" onsubmit="return false">
<input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_mediamall" ></input>
<input type="hidden" name="task" value="addToFav" ></input>
<input type="hidden" name="addMediaId" value="<?php echo $media->id; ?>" ></input>
<input type="hidden" name="delRow" value="<?php echo $del->id; ?>" > </input>
<input type="submit" name="submit2" id="sub" value="<?php if($del->id) { echo '0'; } else { echo '1'; } ?>" ></input>

</form>
```

JQUERY

```
<script>


    $("#sub").click( function() {
      var url=$("#myForm").attr("action");
      $.post(url, $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),function(){
          var val=$("#sub").val()== 1 ? 0 : 1;// toggle value of submit for insert or delete
        $("#sub").val(val);
      });  
    }); 


    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use ajax for that.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
If you don't want to refresh your page

Comment: But if i dont want to show url to my php function ? how can i do that ? because those url will be visible directly from firefox, chrome etc

Comment: Well, I know what you mean. Maybe, there is a solution on websocket side. Hope someone will give us an explanation.